# What formula can I use to get a cell associated with the result of MAX() in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, max, match, google-sheets-formula

[image]

BEST MAX is MAX(B7:X7)

What formula can I use to get the associated date with the BEST MAX?

The pink box should read "7/13", located at G1, and if the next week were the new BEST MAX, then the total would need to read "7/20", located at H1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1, 1+MATCH(B11, B7:X7, 0)))
```

or shorter:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1, MATCH(B11, 7:7, 0)))
```